# Generic functions and value types

Tags: c#, generics

Do generic functions work well with nullable value types, or do they box behind the scenes?

For example I have a helper function like this:

```
public static TResult Return<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator, TResult failureValue)
    where TInput : class
{
    if (o == null) return failureValue;
    return evaluator(o);
}
```

Which I use to offer a fallback value when something is null, eg

```
var log = person.Return(p => p.log, emptylog)
```

So depending on whether `log` is a value or reference type, do I need a specialised version of `Return()` to handle value types without boxing, or is the above good for all cases?

EDIT: I'm curious as to why the author of this http://pastebin.com/vdS1uNu1 has specializations for class -> struct, class -> class, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't box value types - but it *will* cause a new native implementation of the method to be created (at JIT time) each time you use a different value type for `TResult`, whereas all reference types will share the same native code. That's *very* rarely a problem though - it's not like it's a per-call overhead. It's that "create the right native code based on the type argument" that allows it to avoid boxing.

Comment: Thanks. So why does this code, for example, offer specialized implementations for value/ref types? Wouldn't an unconstrained TResult just work? http://pastebin.com/vdS1uNu1

Comment: @user826840: No, because some of those methods use `TResult?` - which is only valid when `TResult` is constrained to be a non-nullable value type.

Comment: But if I do: `public static TResult MyTest<TInput, TResult>(this TInput input, Func<TInput, TResult> lambda)
  {
   return input == null ? default(TResult) : lambda(input);
  }
` it seems to work when returning ref, value, or nullable value types. So there's no point at all in special implementations? I'm just curious why he bothered! Thanks

Comment: @user826840: Look at the signature of `NullOr` when `TResult` is constrained to being a struct - the return type is `TResult?` rather than `TResult`. How would you propose doing that with a single method? You want `foo.NullOr(x => 5)` to return an `int?`, not an `int`.

Comment: Ah I see! So the specialization is to ensure the result is always nullable. Thanks, I was assuming it was to avoid boxing.